# Why do I get the error: "Error found when loading /home/ubuntu/.profile:"?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 8.1. I've created a UEFI Bootable Ubuntu USB Drive by using the software `Universal Installer`, but when I reboot my laptop and click on "Try Ubuntu without installing" I get the following error:

```
Error found when loading /home/ubuntu/.profile:
/usr/sbin/lightdm-session: line 29: .:/home/ubuntu: cannot execute binary file
As a result the session will not be configured correctly
You should fix the problem as soon as feasible
```

Why do I get this? To be honest, I don't the this line 29 is from, so please before disliking and criticising tell me, so I can learn :)

I think it's from the `grub.cfg`, but I don't know. Anyway, here is the `grub.cfg`:

```
if loadfont /boot/grub/font.pf2 ; then
set gfxmode=auto
insmod efi_gop
insmod efi_uga
insmod gfxterm
terminal_output gfxterm
fi

set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray

menuentry "Try Ubuntu without installing" {
set gfxpayload=keep
linux    /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash persistent --
initrd    /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Install Ubuntu" {
set gfxpayload=keep
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash persistent --
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
set gfxpayload=keep
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
menuentry "Check disc for defects" {
set gfxpayload=keep //this is line 29 in the grub.cfg
linux   /casper/vmlinuz.efi  cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent noprompt floppy.allowed_drive_mask=0 ignore_uuid boot=casper integrity-check quiet splash ---
initrd  /casper/initrd.lz
}
```

Honestly, I don't this is the correct file, but I don't know which is.
[This is the USB folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAQIQ.png)

Comment: It's not your `grub.cfg`. [Edit] your question and add the output of `cat ~/.profile`

Comment: I'm on windows now, what should I do to get the output?

Answer (score 0):

You can't fix the problem but there is no need to fix the problem. Test Ubuntu and if you wish to install it, install it and the warning will be gone.

Comment: But when I install directly instead it gives me an internal error

Comment: Which internal error. That's a completely different problem. Install it and ask a new question with your real problem.

Comment: I asked the question because I've tried both of them. However, thanks.